# In knockout when using <select> how to get the selected item to select the correct item on startup when you have an object

Tags: knockout.js, coffeescript

given this coffeescript

```
data =
  Foo: "B"
  Foos: [ "A", "B" ]
  Blah:
    Id: 2
    Name: "B"

  Blahs: [
    Id: 1
    Name: "A"
  ,
    Id: 2
    Name: "B"
   ]


class Vm
    constructor: (data) ->
        @Blah = ko.observable()    
        ko.mapping.fromJS data, {}, this        

vm = new Vm(data)
console.log vm
ko.applyBindings vm;
```

and then given these two dropdown bindings...

```
<select data-bind="options: Blahs,optionsText: 'Name', value: Blah">
<select data-bind="options: Foos, value: Foo">
```

the fiddle:-

http://jsfiddle.net/keith_nicholas/3eYHd/

The strings of Foo sets the selected option on startup correctly,  the one with objects, Blah, doesn't  ( in fact it changes the selected item to be the first in the list)

Is there are simple way to make the select with objects act the same as the one with strings?

Note:  I can do something like

http://jsfiddle.net/keith_nicholas/LJpJw/

```
replaceWithMatching = (prop, list, match) -> 
    prop (x for x in list when x[match]() == prop()[match]())[0]
```

and then

```
replaceWithMatching @Blah, @Blahs(), "Id"
```

to map the existing object to one that exists in the list.  But I was looking for something a bit cleaner / declarative,  perhaps something like :-

like `<select data-bind="options: Blahs,optionsText: 'Name', matchOn: 'Id', value: Blah">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are binding against objects in the `value` binding, then they need to be a reference to the same object.

Basically:

```
var a = { name: "Bob" };
var b = { name: "Bob" };
var c = b;

alert(a === b) //false
alert(b === c) //true
```

So, in your sample you could define the array of choices first and then initialize your selected value to one of the objects in that array.

Here is your sample updated: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/ampys/

Comment: sure, I realise that,  but, the data is coming from some other source.....  so editing that is cheating :)   so I *could* post process the data so that I find matching objects in the list and then make them the same object.  But ideally, since its a "View" issue, there would be way in the view binding to tell it how to match the list and value.

Comment: Yes, in that situation, you have to get the matching reference in your array when you initialize the selected value.  You can use something like `ko.utils.arrayFirst(yourArray, function(item) { item.id === match.id; });`

Comment: There isn't really an easier/cleaner way than in your edit without writing a custom binding.  The custom binding would likely just be the first binding listed (so it runs before options/value), and it would run the matching code on init.